# XML Extended Syntax with personal params

Tags: xml, sapui5

I see this examples:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/25ab54b0113c4914999c43d07d3b71fe.html

I have this my formatter function:

```
rowVisibility: function (oRow, sGrid) {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData("model/file/mapping/map.json", "", false);
        var oGridInfo = oModel.getProperty("/elements")[sGrid];
        var bVisible = true;
        _.forEach(oGridInfo.fields, function (fld) {
            if (oRow[fld] == null)
                bVisible = false;
        });
        return bVisible;
    }
```

And in XML view I try to pass more than one param:

```
visible="{parts:[{path: 'model>'}, {'MY_GRID_NAME'} ], formatter:'ui5bp.Formatter.rowVisibility'}"
```

but it don't work...
How can I send sGrid param? I want create only one formatter function, not one for each sGrid!

Example: the rowVisibility formatter function is called from 3 different context ("context_a", "context_b" and "context_c"). I want have one function called from 3 context (the behavior will different based on the context)

```
visible="{parts:[{path: 'model>'}, {"context_a"} ], formatter:'ui5bp.Formatter.rowVisibility'}"

visible="{parts:[{path: 'model>'}, {"context_b"} ], formatter:'ui5bp.Formatter.rowVisibility'}"

visible="{parts:[{path: 'model>'}, {"context_c"} ], formatter:'ui5bp.Formatter.rowVisibility'}"
```

this is the unique function

```
rowVisibility: function (oRow) {
        ...
}
```

Now instead I have 3 different functions:

```
rowVisibility_contextA: function (oRow) {
            ...
}

rowVisibility_contextB: function (oRow) {
            ...
}

rowVisibility_contextC: function (oRow) {
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On which control are you doing this? The 'visible' property would normally be a boolean value; if you are trying to set a non-boolean value to it there will be an error.

Comment: yes, how you can see in `rowVisibility` function the result is always a boolean.
If I send only `oRow` by `{path: 'model>'}` in debug the function is executed, but if I try to send also `sGrid` the function not start

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your syntax. Check this [link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html). You miss 'path' for 'MY_GRID_NAME'

Comment: but MY_GRID_NAME is not a model property... I can't use `path`

Comment: @bradipo is it a plain string?

Comment: yes, it is a simple string.
I have updated the Q with an example

Comment: @bradipo, thanks for adding more detail. But, I am still a bit confused about your scenario. It might be just me. 'll wait for others to pitch in :) sorry

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use a string literal or variable when using extended syntax. A workaround I've used is to store the value in a model and then use that - it's a bit ugly, but it works (and it's a lot better than having lots of wrapper formatting functions to cater for each case).

Answer (score 0):

Building on **@mjturner**'s answer, I had a need to do exactly this. I would have loved to put the string literal in the `parts` section, but using a View `JSONModel` worked just as well for my needs.

Let's say I have this i18n entry in my `messageBundle.properties` file:

```
Main.IconTabFilter.StatusExpandedMessage=Filtering on {0} projects ...
```

Then, I have this formatter function in a `BaseController` class I've extended from `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller`:

```js
  /**
   * Generic function to format i18n strings given data from XML views. This is a convenience method.
   *
   * @param {string} sKey - this is the i18n key in your messageBundle to use. !!! IMPORTANT !!! this key must be sent through
   *                        a model (like View JSONModel). You cannot pass string literals in the <code>{ parts: [] }</code> array in XML.
   * @param {string} [dynamic] - This function accepts any number of strings (parts) to add to i18n string.
   *                             These dynamic strings are added to i18n with <code>Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)</code>.
   */
  i18nFormatter: function(sKey) {
    if (sKey) {
      return this.getResourceBundle().getText(sKey, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else { 
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Then from your view's controller, set up a View `JSONModel` (or use an existing):

```js
var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
  i18n: {
    StatusExpandedMessage: 'Main.IconTabFilter.StatusExpandedMessage'
  }
});
this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, 'view');
```

Now that the formatter has all the means to retrieve your data, let's set up the XML view:

```xml
<Text text="{ parts: [{ path: 'view>/i18n/StatusExpandedMessage' }, { path: 'Description' }], formatter: '.i18nFormatter' }" />
```

You can re-use this formatter anywhere you want to perform this same action. Just always ensure your first 'part' is the string key of your i18n message.